# Como obtengo el valor de un checkbox con ts

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Estoy de desarrolando con angular y Necesito obtener el valor de un checkbox que esta en el html, en mi ts para guardar el elemento como true o false
mi codigo html es:

```
<div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="true" name="activo" id="activo" [(ngModel)]="user.alta">
                        <label class="form-check-label text-dark" for="activo">
                          Activo?
                        </label>
```

cuando esta seleccionado si se guarda como true, pero cuando no esta seleccionada no se guarda ese atributo pero yo necesito que se guarde como false

- alta es un atributo de user

```
    export class Usuario {
    _id:string;
    usuario:string;
    password:string;
    alta:boolean;

    Usuario(_id?:string ,  usuario?:string ,  password?:string , alta?:boolean ,  perfil?:string){
        this._id = _id ;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.password = password;
        this.alta = alta;
    }
}
```

- y este mi codigo en ts

```
export class UsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
    user:Usuario;
  usuarios:Array<Usuario>;

  constructor(private usuarioService:UsuarioService, private _toastr:ToastrService) {
    this.user = new Usuario ();
    this.usuarios = new Array<Usuario>();
    this.user.activo=false;
  }
guardarUsuario(){
    this.usuarioService.addUsuario(this.user).subscribe(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
          this._toastr.success("Usuario creado","Exito")
          this.refrescarUsuarios();
        },
        (error) =>{
          this._toastr.error(error, "Error")
        }
      )
}
refrescarUsuarios(){
    this.user.alta=false;
    this.user = new Usuario ();
    this.usuarios = new Array<Usuario>();
    this.usuarioService.getUsuarios().subscribe(
      (result)=>{
        result.forEach(element => {
          Object.assign(this.user,element);
          this.usuarios.push(this.user);
          this.user= new Usuario();
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: No veo ningun error en el código. Hice un ejemplo en stackblitz y me funciona bien. Te comparto el ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-370057 En caso de no ser la solución, puedes actualizar la pregunta con mas detalles

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con mas detalles

Comment: acabo de agregar una solucion. Te agradezco que si encuentra que soluciona el problema, la marques como correcta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios problemas en el código:

1. Me parece que estas usando 2 propiedades para manejar el estado del checkbox `alta` y `activo`. `activo` no existe en la interface asumo que es un error
2. En la función `refrescarUsuarios` cada vez que se obtiene nueva información se le asigna nuevas propiedades a la variable `usuario` en esta linea `Object.assign(this.user,element);` pero 2 lineas más abajo se sobre escribe con un objecto nuevo usuario.

Cree una solución en Stackblitz utilizando como base el código de la pregunta.

Además aqui puedes encontrar la solucion al problema

```
export class UsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  public user: Usuario | null = new Usuario();
  public usuarios: Usuario[] = [];

  constructor(
    private usuarioService: UsuarioService, 
    private toast: ToastService
  ) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usuarioService.getUsuarios().subscribe((result) => {
      this.usuarios = result;
    })
  }

  public guardarUsuario(): void {    
      this.usuarioService
          .addUsuario(this.user)
          .subscribe(
            (result) => {              
              this.toast.success('Usuario creado, Exito')
              this.refrescarUsuarios();
            },
            (error) =>{
              this.toast.error('Error')
            }
        )
  }

  public refrescarUsuarios(): void {      
      this.user = new Usuario();      
      this.usuarioService
          .getUsuarios()
          .subscribe(
            (result)=> {
              this.usuarios = result;
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            }
          )
    }
}
```

Por favor ignora los archivos de `ToastService` y `UsuarioService` solo hace "mimica" de las clases que debes de tener implementada en el proyecto

Ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-370057